# Lighting looks diffrent in my project in Unity than this project in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, mesh, lighting, terrain

I am following a tutorial series on Youtube. Here's his channel btw (https://www.youtube.com/c/SebastianLague). On the github repository (https://github.com/SebLague/Procedural-Landmass-Generation) that comes from the video series explaining how to implement procedural generation (https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLFt_AvWsXl0eBW2EiBtl_sxmDtSgZBxB3). I've followed his tutorial series up to episode 6. I wanted to compare what I have done and what he has done to see if what I wrote matched what he wrote. Everything seems fine expect for the lighting of the scene. It has boggled my mind since everything seems to be the same. I have the same project settings as the other scene. Here are some screenshots of what I'm talking about.

**Sebastian Lague's Project**
[image: Sebastian Lague's Project]

**My Project**
[image: My Project]

My theory is that it has to do with the version of unity I'm using, but I honestly don't think that's it. It's just weird that this is the case.

Comment: are the coordinates of the light the same as the tutorial?

Comment: yes, also the light is directional. Location does not matter, only rotation